# Deleting files with python. Shutil raises an Access Denied, even though I have full rights to the files

Tags: python, windows

So I have a backup solution, and before I was using batch to take care of backups, and it created and deleted just fine. I moved to python to add additional functionality, but it no longer will delete backups completely, having me manually delete backups every few days. Below is the suspect code.. But I posted the whole thing just in case. Thanks!

Here is the Full Code: http://pastebin.com/ziQuk05B

```
def del_rw(action, name, exc):
    try:
        os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
        os.remove(name)
    except Exception,e:
        send_email('There was a problem deleting files', 'del_rw function\n' + str(e))

for dir in previous_backups:
    if os.path.getmtime(directory + PAD + dir) == timestamp[0]:
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(directory + PAD, dir), onerror=del_rw)
        except Exception,e:
            send_email('There was a problem deleting old backups', str(e))
    pass
```

There seems to be a problem with either read only or system permissions...but it deleted it before so I believe I have permission, just something with the read only won't let me force delete it.

Comment: Please post the entire error message, including any traceback.

Comment: do you have write access to the _folder_? When you delete a file you are modifying the folder that contains the file.

Comment: @Rob [Error 5] Access is denied: '\\\\backups/2016-04-04_0030\\Public\\000\\sadf'

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I do. But when I modify it on error, I only change the file. Should I change permissions on the entire folder before I do any deleting? It deletes everything else just fine and deletes about 90% of the problems with the onerror function

Comment: @DanGetz I know what user and I gave that permission. That was something I checked when creating.

Comment: @DanGetz Im reading that now, but it's unclear to me how that differs from the solution I have in place.

Comment: @xadves Ah, I see that now. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: The error is from the `remove()` call, not the `chmod()`, right?

Comment: @DanGetz Id like to say so, but I don't know because the way this code has to run is production, and for it to be in production it has to be an exe, and I dont get enough error to know. This does not happen in the test enviroment.

Comment: The Windows file permission model has separate rights for writing files vs deleting files. There's also a "delete child" right that can be assigned to a directory in order to allow deleting its files, even if the files don't otherwise allow this. An administrator (elevated) should also have `SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege`, which when enabled allow all read and write/delete access, respectively, to a file or directory. Initially these privileges are present in an administrator token, but not enabled. You need PyWin32 or ctypes to enable privileges.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still having this issue, my problem was some of my users filenames were too long. Windows allows 260 Characters and some of my users exceed that.

Thanks!